# Chrome pageAction icon not showing except when debugging

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get a Chrome pageAction icon to appear, but it only briefly flashes up as a page loads and then disappears.

However, the thing that has me flummoxed is that when I use the Dev Tools debugger and stick a break-point on the chrome.pageAction.show() call, it works perfectly! Here's my manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "20130409-test",
    "description": "Page action icons don't work!",
    "version": "0.1",
    "icons": {"16": "icon16.png", "48": "icon48.png", "128": "icon128.png"},
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "page_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "icon19.png",
            "38": "icon38.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Page action title here!"
    }
}
```

And my background.js page is:

```
chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(details) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(details.tabId);
        chrome.pageAction.setTitle({
            "tabId": details.tabId,
            "title": "url=" + details.url
        });
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"], types: ["main_frame"]},
    ["requestHeaders"]
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A page action which is bound to a specific tab is removed when the tab's page unloads.

`chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders` is triggered when a new request is about to start. This means that the previous page is still being displayed. When you call `chrome.pageAction.show`, the page action is activated for the current page, and disappears as soon as the requested page is loaded.

By setting a breakpoint with the developer tools (or using the `debugger;` statement), `chrome.pageAction.show` is sufficiently delayed, and the page action shows *after* the new page is loaded.

Use [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html), or the [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) event unless you want to see the URL as soon as the request is initiated.

### Method 1: Content script

The content script should be injected only at the top-level frame. Preferrably as soon as possible, so with `"run_at":"document_start"`.

```js
// PART of manifest.json
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["contentscript.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "all_frames": false
}], ...........

// Content script: contentscript.js
chrome.extension.sendMessage({type:'showPageAction'});

// Background page: background.js
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender) {
    if (message && message.type === 'showPageAction') {
        var tab = sender.tab;
        chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id);
        chrome.pageAction.setTitle({
            tabId: tab.id,
            title: 'url=' + tab.url
        });
    }
});
```

The disadvantage of this method is that it does not work on restricted URLs. E.g. you won't see a page action for data-URIs, the Chrome web store, etc. This issue does not appear in the next method.

### Method 2: `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`

```js
// background.js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    chrome.pageAction.setTitle({
        tabId: tab.id,
        title: 'url=' + tab.url
    });
});
```

Note: [`onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) is called more than once per tab load. Initially once when the URL is changed, then twice for each (top-level/sub) frame. It would be nice to reduce the number of unnecessary `chrome.pageAction` calls, but there's no straightforward method for it.
If you only check the value of [`changeInfo.url`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#property-onUpdated-changeInfo), the page action will not show up if you refresh the page.